# What Causes Instruction Replay Overhead in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, overhead

I ran the visual profiler on a CUDA application of mine. The application calls a single kernel multiple times if the data is too large. This kernel has no branching.

The profiler reports a **high instruction replay overhead** of **83.6%** and a **high global memory instruction replay overhead** of **83.5%**.

Here is how the kernel generally looks:

```
// Decryption kernel
__global__ void dev_decrypt(uint8_t *in_blk, uint8_t *out_blk){

    __shared__ volatile word sdata[256];
    register uint32_t data;

    // Thread ID
#define xID (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x)
#define yID (threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y)
    uint32_t tid = xID + yID * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
#undef xID
#undef yID

    register uint32_t pos4 = tid%4;
    register uint32_t pos256 = tid%256;
    uint32_t blk = pos256&0xFC;

    // Indices
    register uint32_t index0 = blk + (pos4+3)%4;
    register uint32_t index1 = blk + (pos4+2)%4;

    // Read From Global Memory
    b0[pos256] = ((word*)in_blk)[tid+4] ^ dev_key[pos4];

    data  = tab(0,sdata[index0]);
    data ^= tab(1,sdata[index1]);
    sdata[pos256] = data ^ tab2[pos4];

    data  = tab(0,sdata[index0]);
    data ^= tab(1,sdata[index1]);
    sdata[pos256] = data ^ tab2[2*pos4];

    data  = tab(0,sdata[index0]);
    data ^= tab(1,sdata[index1]);
    data ^= tab2[3*pos4];

    ((uint32_t*)out_blk)[tid] = data + ((uint32_t*)in_blk)[tid];
}
```

As you can see there are no branches. The threads will initially read from global memory based on thread ID + 16 bytes. They will then write to an output buffer after performing an operation with data from global memory based on their thread ID.

Any ideas why this kernel would have so much overhead?

Comment: @talonmies It's a macro that I use to access constant memory. tab2 is also constant memory. This is not what my kernel actually looks like. However, this is how it generally behaves.

Comment: Ok then the serialization is probably because of the constant memory access. If all threads in a warp won't be accessing the same word in constant memory, you can get serialization.

Comment: @talonmies So even constant memory access has to be accessed a certain way to be coalesced? The CUDA C programming guide made no mention of this.

Comment: @talonmies I changed my code to create 32 instances of the table (still plenty of constant memory). The profiler is reporting the same thing. Should I perhaps rearrange the table so that adjacent threads are accessing adjacent words?

Comment: Unless every thread in a warp accesses the same word in constant memory,you get serialization. If you want random or semi random access, use global memory or a texture, not constant memory.

Comment: @talonmies At this moment I'm trying to figure out how to transfer a 2D table on host memory to device memory, and bind that to a 2D texture reference.  I'm thinking I'm just supposed to use cudaMallocPitch and cudaBindTexture2D, but I'm unfamiliar with the process. Do you have any tips on how this is done?

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the help. There is no longer any issue being reported after I bound the tables to 2D texture memory, and it appears that I kernel runs a bit faster. Can you put your advice in the form of an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the instruction replay in this case is non-uniform constant memory access within a warp. In you code, `tab` is stored in constant memory and indexed according to some combination of thread index and data stored shared memory. The result would appear to be non-uniform access threads within the same warp. Constant memory is really intended for cases where all threads in a warp access the same word, then the value can be broadcast from constant memory cache in a single operation, otherwise warp serialization occurs.

In cases where non-uniform access of small, read-only datasets is required, it would probably be better to bind the data to a texture than store it is constant memory.